# TortoiseSVN Switch errors

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to switch an existing trunk check out to a specific branch, I get this error:

```
Can't move 
'C:\Work\project123\include\.svn\tmp\all-wcprops' 
to 
'C:\Work\project123\include\.svn\all-wcprops': 
The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
```

I've run cleanup but no change.

Comment: Oh man, welcome to hell!

Comment: One suggestion might be to do a search+delete on the `wcprops` files within the working copy, but I don't want the responsibility of saying so for sure, back'em up first - I had to do this the other day just to check-in a single file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have any local modifications, just delete `C:\Work\project123\include`, `update` to get a fresh copy and then `switch` again.  **Please backup first!**

**Update:** One of the reasons could be that the files in `C:\Work\project123\include\.svn\tmp` got locked by an antivirus or some indexing service.  To find out which process has handles to these files you can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)'s search function.

Comment: yeah, but I want to know WHY it's bust!

Comment: @John, you know, programs have bugs ;)  I don't think it was done intentionally.

Comment: Does it happen every time, actually?

Comment: It does now... is it a known bug then? What has gone wrong? A non-atomic file/dir-copy?

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug in Window 7, slated to be fixed in SP 1:

http://subversion.wandisco.com/blogs/windows-7-bogus-errorfilecorrupt-error-.html

There is now a hotfix available:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982927/en-us